# Show that the function $g(z) = f(e ^z )$ is not a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f :\mathbb  C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an entire function.

Show that the function $g(z) = f(e ^z )$ is not a polynomial.

What is the technique to show a function is  a  polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common way to show that functions cannot be (non-constant) polynomials is that (non-constant) polynomials only have finitely many roots.

If $g(z)$ were polynomial, then $g(z) = g(0)$ would have finitely many solutions.  However, $g(2\pi i k) = f(e^{2\pi i k}) = f(1) = g(0)$ holds true for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Seems we don't need the hypothesis of f being entire.

Comment: @learnmore: I hink he is referring to the value $g(0)=f(1)$ , where $f(1)$ is seen as a complex constant.

Comment: thanks for the answer; i got it

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(e^z)$ is a polynomial. Then so is $f'(e^z)$ and its derivative :

$f'(e^z)e^z$ . But $e^z (a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n)$ is not a polynomial. If it was,

( a non-constant) polynomial, $e^z =\frac {p(z)}{q(z)} $ would have singularities, or $e^z$ would be a polynomial itself. But, "borrowing" (ripping of) Rolf's answer, $e^z$ is not a polynomial since it has no zeros.